# Ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java` in Amazon SageMaker Jupyter Notebook

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am importing the tabula library and when I call this library's methods, I receive the following error in SageMaker.

```
JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

How can I install Java to SageMaker?

Below is my code:

```
import tabula
pdf_path = "https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/raw/master/tests/resources/data.pdf"
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True)
```

Once I enter in this code, I receive the error message that SageMaker does not have Java.